# Alinhar Divs Corretamente

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Olá, tenho o seguinte CSS

```
.control-label{
    width: 100px;    
    text-align: center;
}
.input-mini {
    width: 85px;    
}
```

E a seguinte estrutura de formulário

```
<div class="control-group">
    <div class="controls" style="float:left; margin-left: 5px;">
        <div id="textinput" class="control-label" style="float:left; margin-left: 5px;">Base</div>
        <div id="textinput" class="control-label" style="float:left; margin-left: 5px;">P. Moto</div>
        <div id="textinput" class="control-label" style="float:left; margin-left: 5px;">P. Carro</div>
        <div id="textinput" class="control-label" style="float:left; margin-left: 5px;">P. Van</div>
        <div id="textinput" class="control-label" style="float:left; margin-left: 5px;">P. Caminhão</div>
        <div id="textinput" class="control-label" style="float:left; margin-left: 5px;">R. Moto</div>
        <div id="textinput" class="control-label" style="float:left; margin-left: 5px;">R. Carro</div>
        <div id="textinput" class="control-label" style="float:left; margin-left: 5px;">R. Van</div>
        <div id="textinput" class="control-label" style="float:left; margin-left: 5px;">R. Caminhão</div>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="control-group">

    <div class="controls" style="float:left; margin-left: 5px;">
        <div class="input-mini" style="float:left; margin-left: 5px;">
            <strong>BAIRRO</strong>
        </div>
        <input id="textinput" name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="0.00" class="input-mini" style="float:left; margin-left: 5px;">
        <input id="textinput" name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="0.00" class="input-mini" style="float:left; margin-left: 5px;">
        <input id="textinput" name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="0.00" class="input-mini" style="float:left; margin-left: 5px;">
        <input id="textinput" name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="0.00" class="input-mini" style="float:left; margin-left: 5px;">
        <input id="textinput" name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="0.00" class="input-mini" style="float:left; margin-left: 5px;">
        <input id="textinput" name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="0.00" class="input-mini" style="float:left; margin-left: 5px;">
        <input id="textinput" name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="0.00" class="input-mini" style="float:left; margin-left: 5px;">
        <input id="textinput" name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="0.00" class="input-mini" style="float:left; margin-left: 5px;">
        <input id="textinput" name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="0.00" class="input-mini" style="float:left; margin-left: 5px;">
    </div>
</div>
```

Mas na hora de visualizar, fica desalinhado os títulos... Dessa forma:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

## Adendo

Lembrando que eu farei um foreach () no segundo div, para repetir os campos conforme os bairros...

Comment: Coloca os títulos dentro de um `<label> Títulos </label>`.

Comment: Coloquei eles todos dentro de um label... E coloquei como float:left.. mas ficou tudo junto um com o outro..

Comment: Por mais que o width dos inputs e dos labels são 85, deveria encaixar, mas não deu não....

Comment: Coloca num JsFiddle pra nós.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/thje3g52/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mano, eu dei um CTRL C CTRL V nos campos. Mas você entenderá os esquemas:

### HTML

```
<div class="control-group">

<div class="controls" style="float:left; margin-left: 5px;">
    <div class="input-mini" style=" margin-left: 5px;">
        <strong>BAIRRO</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Bairro</label>
        <input id="textinput" name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="0.00" class="input-mini">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Bairro</label>
        <input id="textinput" name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="0.00" class="input-mini">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Bairro</label>
        <input id="textinput" name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="0.00" class="input-mini">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Bairro</label>
        <input id="textinput" name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="0.00" class="input-mini">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Bairro</label>
        <input id="textinput" name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="0.00" class="input-mini">
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.input-mini {
    width: 85px;
    display:inline-block;
}

label {
    width: 100px;   
}
div.form-group{
    width: 100px;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

As `labels` ficam dentro do FORM.
Criei uma classe `form-group` e coloquei os campos dentro e as labels correspondentes.

No **CSS** você define `display:inline-block` e tira os `float:left` do HTML.

Comment: Quase isso Diego, porém, eu vou ter que fazer uma listagem de bairros em PHP, isto significa que se repetiriam todos os títulos dos campos, por esse motivo eu fiz separadamente, para que no segundo div eu possa fazer o foreach($bairros as $valor)

Comment: Nada de usar tabelas ?

Comment: Não, neste caso não... Pois o form inteiro já está em div... em tabela seria fácil mesmo rs

Comment: Mas você pode fazer um ìf` verificando se é a primeira linha. Você mostra as `labels` apenas na primeira.

Comment: Gambiarra.. rsrsrs

Comment: É uma alternativa @DiegoSouza

Comment: Fiz com sua alternativa, acertei e ficou certinho, grato